# Событие для отслеживания изменения содержимого input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос не типичный, как может показаться из названия. Есть текстовый `input`, куда вставляется ссылка на аватар пользователя. Ссылка вставляется из открывшейся в новом окне формы (внутри находится iframe и править нет возможности). События `.on`, `.live` и `.change` оказались бессильны.

Вот сам принцип:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли еще какие-то способы проверки содержимого поля или его изменения?

Минимальный пример:

```js
setTimeout("$('#test').val('link')", 1000);
$('#test').change(function(){alert('Элемент был изменен.');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Comment: Каким образом текст вставляется в `<input>`? Посредством JS? Про `.live()` вообще лучше не вспоминать, ибо это дело устарело очень давно. `on` и `live`, кстати, - это вообще не события.

Comment: По-хорошему, думаю, это окно должно само кидать событие onchange

Comment: без [mcve] ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: кроме того: `.on` и `.live` это не события

Comment: @Grundy да вроде бы всё понятно - обновляют через `.value`, который событий вроде не кидает

Comment: О том, что `.on` и `.live` не события я знаю, просто использовал их в связке с jQuery. Не описывать же их в вопросе вместе с обрабатываемыми событиями. Про "Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример" что можно сказать? Это пустой `input` в который втыкается значение с задержкой. Сейчас добавлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// есть текстовый инпутъ
const input = document.getElementById("input");
// куда вставляется
setTimeout(() => input.value = 'какая то шляпа', 777);
// И никак не поймать событиями..
input.addEventListener('change', () => {console.log('triggered');});    
input.addEventListener('input', () => {console.log('triggered');});
// Но можно контролировать доступ к value, если его переназначить
Object.defineProperty(input,"value",{
    get(){
        return this.getAttribute("value");
    },
    set(value){
        console.log("Поймал", value);
        this.setAttribute("value",value);
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробуем применить.

Comment: Все отлично, только немного поправьте код на `get: function()` и `set: function(value)`, а то jshint ругается на  "Missing property name".

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev мой eslint молчит. Я слегка погуглил на тему `jshint es6 short method definition Missing property name`, ничего не нашел. Может быть, имеет смысл задать на эту тему вопрос - почему ваш jshint ругается

Comment: Может смысл и есть, но, меня и так все устраивает) Еще раз спасибо за помощь!